# Bookings Engine | Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am planning to use StackExchange.Redis c# wrapper for my Bookings Engine.
But I am concerned about bookings that would be registered within the same date range.

How can I ensure that no overlapping orders can be created?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an unique key for your datas.
2 main solutions for that :

**SOLUTION 1 : Store unique size in REDIS** 
to keep track of booking numbers

1. name of key : `bookings:size`
2. on evey booking, get the bookings:size and then `add +1` after booking.
3. use booking:size as key like this

   bookings:order-1

   bookings:order-2

   bookings:order-3

**SOLUTION 2 : generate an unique key in your program** 
1. generate an unique key in your code (with as safe UUID generator is best practice)
2. use it like this

bookings:order-123GSDDG34TERG34T34EG45G5F54Y456H56HH57J45VF43

bookings:order-12234535646323535756854778566746756HH57J45VF43

bookings:order-7777777777777777777743ERGSDFG4556H6776H76H7H7H

**Versus?**
I really prefer the Solution2, because is the best way to have unique keys without asking for server. This is a common Rest practice. Also allows to split key upon a shard of redis server.... etc.